# Background-attachment: fixed not working in jquery mobile phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

How can I set a background image which is not scrolling along with the content. I'm using jquery mobile and phonegap. I try to use background-attachment: fixed but the image is not going in fullscreen.

```
<div data-role="page" class="background">
</div>
```

My css:

```
.background {
background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment:scroll;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: First of all you need to make sure this "background" div is going to be a container for the rest of your site, otherwise it won't work as a background for the entire site. Second, if that first case is true (which it is), why not just use that CSS in your <body> tag instead of your <div>?

Comment: I tried to use that, still no luck. I'm using jquerymobile in phonegap. When I use the css in body, the image is there but still its not fixed.

Comment: Does the image show up at all? Can you post some code of what you've tried so far (HTML and CSS, with any relevant jQuery), and what--exactly--isn't working for you?

Comment: Yes the image showed up, http://pastebin.com/0c4BjK8Q above is the css. The problem is, the image is stretched all the way the length of the contents. I just need it to be fixed in the screen size while scrolling the contents.

Comment: I've added an answer that I think might be helpful. Let's move the comment discussion there as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I had to tackle this problem, the work around (as far as I am aware it hasn't changed in iOS7) is to create a separate div (call it the "background" div), set its position to fixed and insert your desired background image inside this div.

Set the z-index of this div so that it sits underneath the rest of your content.

iOS webview will respect fixed positioned divs but not `background-attachment: fixed;`

Set the background once, inside the `<body>` of your html file(s) but outside your subsequent pages.

Here's how I did it and it worked really well.

```
<div class="background"><img src="img/Background_Dark.png" width="100%"/></div>
```

and the css

```
.background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: -10000;
}
```

Comment: This works amazingly well. Going to deploy it to iOS and if this works there, you are my hero.

Comment: It should do, let me know. If not I'll double check my code and update the answer but I'm still using it successfully in iOS 8.x

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to cut out half of the CSS. Start with this:

```
.background {
  background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Notice that I changed `background-attachment: scroll;` to `background-attachment: fixed;`. The default value of background-attachment is scroll, so you don't need to include it anyway, but that does the opposite of what you are trying to do.

Second, can you upload the bg.png to imgur or some other site so that we can have a better example of what you're trying to do? And also fill in your div with some sample content of similar length to your actual content? **Since this is a div and not the body** of your website, the div is collapsed *unless there is content inside*, and the div will grow to fill the content.

**This means if you set *background-size: 100% 100%;* you will be stretching the image as far as the content** of the div; which isn't what you want. You only want the background image to fill the viewport. Setting `background-attachment: fixed;` accomplishes this.

Comment: Here is the image http://imgur.com/lDU0lXZ, i want it to be fullscreen in any screen sizes and fixed. My css above achieve to be fullscreen but not fixed. Making attachment to fixed and removing the other make the image not fit. http://pastebin.com/edLDj4i1 a sample content for div. Its always scrollable since it will be used as mobile app.

Comment: I'm still not convinced I know how to do this using background of a single empty (theoretically) div and just CSS. However, since you're familiar with jQuery, check out [this jQuery method](http://j.eremy.net/set-element-height-to-viewport/) for dynamically finding the height of the viewport and setting the div height equal to that. Then perhaps you can set `overflow: auto;` to scroll the content only when necessary.

Comment: Alternatively, use two divs (or body and a div, preferrably) for your background image and your content; check out this [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) link for help on making that work. Sorry I cannot be of more help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iscroll` plugin.
Page in `jquery` mobile executed by java script source code and in some of the elements changing in `css` not works.